# How to generate patterns according count?

Tags: java, design-patterns

How to generate patterns like below if 
input number:2
input number of lines:5

```
2
33
444
5555
66666
```

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    System.out.println("Input a number(0-9):");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNo = sc1.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input number of lines:");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNoLine = sc2.nextInt();
    for (i=inputNo;i<=9;i++)
    {
        count++;
        if(count>inputNoLine)
        {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I only able to code as above.Any suggestion?
Thank you.

Comment: The pattern is the number should be display 1 on first line, 2 times on 2nd line, 3 times on 3rd .. on so on ?

Comment: @user1504015 what will be the pattern if user enter inputNo as 3 and inputNoLine as 5

Comment: @Bingo The pattern will become 3
44
555
6666
77777

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I guess this is what you needed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Input a number(0-9):");
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inputNo = sc1.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Input number of lines:");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    int inputNoLine = sc2.nextInt();

    for(int line=1 ; line <=inputNoLine; line++) {
        for(int count=0; count<line; count++) {
            System.out.print(inputNo);
        }
        System.out.println();
        inputNo++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Input a number(0-9):");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNo = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input number of lines:");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNoLine = sc2.nextInt();
        int count = 1;
        for (int i=0; i < inputNoLine; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(inputNo);
            }
            count++;
            inputNo++;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There were some mistakes... I have edited with the working code.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i =1; i<=5 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
22
333
4444
55555
```

Comment: and what about user input??

Answer (score 1):

There you go :

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("Input a number(0-9):");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNo = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input number of lines:");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNoLine = sc2.nextInt();        
        for (int i = 0; i < inputNoLine; ++i,++inputNo) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j) {
                     System.out.print(inputNo);
            }
            System.out.println();           
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException,
            UnsupportedEncodingException, ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Input a number(0-9):");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNo = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input number of lines:");
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int inputNoLine = sc2.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputNoLine; i++,inputNo++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < inputNo; j++) {
                System.out.print(inputNo);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that for inputNo 3 and inputNoLine 5 - output would be:

```
3
44
555
6666
77777
```

---

try this:

```
int times = 1;
    for (int i=inputNo;i<=inputNoLine;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=times;j++) {
          System.out.print(i);
      }
     times++;
     System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: thnx for your reply.but your code generate 3
44
555 if inputNo 3 and inputNoLine 5

Comment: @user1504015 seems you missed the condition `int i=inputNo;i<=inputNoLine;i++`

Comment: @user1504015 in condition part its `inputNoLine` not `inputNo` thats why you getting only 3 lines